# How to set date if single date picker is true using daterangepicker?

Tags: jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker

I am using [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) to select a date.

The picker should has one date without range start and end.

Here's my settings for the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="event_date_start"]').daterangepicker({
        drops: 'down',
        showDropdowns: false,
        singleDatePicker: true,
        autoApply: true,
        timePicker: false,
        minimumNights: 0,
        minDate: moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        },
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
    });
...
```

At this moment, I set `singleDatePicker` as true, and how to set the date without start and end, only one date?

Without the setting(if singleDatePicker is false), I can set start and end dates dynamically using setStartDate and setEndDate like this.

```
$('input[name="event_date_start"]').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
$('input[name="event_date_start"]').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

But I want to set only one date without any range.

Is there any function like `setDate` rather than `setStartDate` or `setEndDate`?

Answer (score 0):

in the [documentation](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage):

`singleDatePicker:` (true/false) Show only a single calendar to choose one date, instead of a range picker with two calendars. The start and end dates provided to your callback will be the same single date chosen.

you just work wit the start date.

Comment: Did you try to use only `setStartDate`? If I use only `setStartDate`, the calendar has end date as well even without setting the end date.

Comment: Regarding my check, I should use both `setStartDate` and `setEndDate`.

Comment: ok but i dont understand why you are using both with sigle date picker

Comment: Basically, I set the initial date using `setStartDate`, and after a while, I need to update the date using `setStartDate` again. At this moment, I can see that the second set time has became end date and the first set time has became start date. Hope this makes you sense.